# want to call other activity in different class file

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

```
public class allmain extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView allfurniture;

    TextView aaa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all);
        //allfurniture = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.allfurniture);
        aaa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aaa);
        aaa.setText("asdafdfdafaf");
    }
}
```

here the all named layout file is for fragment class but i want to do coding of recyclerview and adapter class so what to do in it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
   holder.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(holder.context(),Activity.class))
```

Comment: `but i want to do coding of recyclerview and adapter class` this is what OP is asking for, are you sure your answer is correct for this question ?

Comment: You mean start the recyclerView?

Comment: yes in fragment we need to code differently then simple java file so i want to class fregment activity in the java file